# How do I send nginx access and error logs to syslog?

Tags: server, nginx, logging, rsyslog

I have rsyslog configured to ship logs to another server. I have been trying to setup nginx and rsyslog to use a socket, like /dev/log, to transfer logs into the local rsyslog and then let it handle how to handle them. If log server location changes, I'd like to have one place to look.

I don't want to use localhost because I don't want to deal with firewall configuration issues in the future and I imagine it would be more robust.

How do I use sockets with rsyslog? 
Should I just give up on this idea and send them to localhost?

Comment: did you get something for sending the ERROR logs ? If yes, please post the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't come up with a good solution.